# How to create a JavaScript interpreter in JavaScript using eval?

Tags: javascript, eval, interpreter, jquery-terminal

It should be simple to create JavaScript intepreter in JavaScript using `eval`. I got this (using jQuery terminal):

```
term = $('#term_demo').terminal(function(command, term) {
    if (command !== '') {
        var result = window.eval("(" + command + ")");
        if (result !== undefined) {
            term.echo(String(result));
        }
    } else {
       term.echo('');
    }
}, {
    greetings: 'Javascript Interpreter',
    name: 'js_demo',
    height: 200,
    prompt: 'js> '
});
```

[Demo](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/#demo)

but it don't work when I execute `function foo() { ... }` the `foo` is not defined I need to use `foo = function() { ... }`. eval act like executed within `(function() { <code> })()`. Can it be there more complicated code that will not work too?

Is it possible to create a JavaScript interpreter using simple code without use the of [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js), that will work the same as browser console?

Comment: jQuery terminal does not really look "simple". What is your goal, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @RobW By simple I mean the interpreter function (8 line of code and it can have 2), this don't work `function foo(x) { return x+x; }` and `foo(10)`

Comment: Why don't you want to use js.js?

Comment: @Alex Because js.js is `594KB` and JS already have interpreter it's call `eval` and it have `4b` (few more if I want to actually use in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a bookmarklet which appends a kind of REPL in a page, designed for the major five browsers (Chrome 1+, IE 6+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Opera 9+<sup>Can't remember the exacte version</sup>).
The core component, which evaluates the code is posted below, slightly modified + annotated.

```
/**
 * Evaluates some code in the global scope.
 * @param String code: Code to eval
 * @return Stringified result, prefixed with 'E:' if error.
 */
function globalEval(/*string*/ code) {
    var win = window, r, raw;
    try {
        if (win.execScript) { // eval in IE sucks, so use execScript instead
            r = win.$_$_$globalEval$_$_$ = {c:code};
            win.execScript('try{$_$_$globalEval$_$_$.r=eval($_$_$globalEval$_$_$.c);}catch(e){$_$_$globalEval$_$_$.e=e}');
            // /*Optional clean-up:*/ delete win.$_$_$globalEval$_$_$;
            if (r.e) throw r.e; // Error
            raw = r.r;
        } else {
            raw = win.eval(code);
        }
        r = '' + raw; // Stringify in the try-block
                      // It is possible that an error is thrown
                      // for example, for the following code: ({toString:1})
    } catch(err) {
        r = (err + ''); // Convert error to string
        // IE: If found, "[object" will be at index zero, which is falsy
        if (!r.indexOf('[object')) r = err.message;
        // r = 
        r = 'E:' + (raw=r);
    } finally {
        // raw = unmodified result (or Error instance)
        // FOR THIS EXAMPLE, raw is not used, and string r is returned
        return /*string*/ r;
    }
}
```

I've implemented the functionality in a form, which contains several controls including an input+output textarea.

Note: The code is evaluated in the global context. And such, any variables in `code` will be leaked to the global scope. For an interpreter, you could use an iframe to create a new scope (and modify `var win` in my function).

```
var win = frames['name_of_frame'], ... // or
var win = frame_DOM_element.contentWindow, ...
```

Comment: I prefer global scope since I want to give a way to interact with the page. I thought that I need to put command within parentheses but it look like I don't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis you're appending around your incoming command produces illegal syntax. You should wrap it with an [anonymous self-executing function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) instead.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bW6Fv/1/

```
var command = "function foo(x){return x+x;} alert(foo(10));";

window.eval("!function(){" + command + "}()");​
```

### EDIT

If you want your evaluated scripts to be available globally, you'll have to leave them unwrapped or explicitly assign values to the global window object.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bW6Fv/2/

```
var command = "window.foo = function(x){return x+x;}; alert(foo(10));";

window.eval("!function(){ " + command + "}();");
window.eval("alert(foo(20));");

command = "function bar(x){return x / 2;}; alert(bar(10));";

window.eval(command);
window.eval("alert(bar(20));");
```

Comment: Thanks I use it in one code, but what about state between calls `eval("(function() { function foo(x) { return x+x; } })()"` and `eval("(function() { alert(foo(10)); }"` different context foo is undefined, how can I handle them?

Comment: @jcubic In your first code, `function foo` is created **locally**. You have to hack a lot if you want to change that JavaScript **feature**.